# How can I use virtual joystick for control fps character controller?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my virtual joystick controller script. Now how can i use this for control fps character controller movement both forward and side?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using System.Collections;

public class JoyStickController : MonoBehaviour , IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler ,IPointerDownHandler{

private Image bgImg;
private Image joyStickImg;
public Vector3 InputDirection{ set; get; }
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    bgImg = GetComponent<Image> ();
    joyStickImg = transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<Image> ();
    InputDirection = Vector3.zero;
}
public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped){
    Vector2 pos = Vector2.zero;
    if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle (bgImg.rectTransform,
        ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos)) {
        pos.x = (pos.x / (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x));
        pos.y = (pos.y / (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y));
        float x = (bgImg.rectTransform.pivot.x == 1) ? pos.x * 2 + 1 : pos.x * 2 - 1;
        float y = (bgImg.rectTransform.pivot.y == 1) ? pos.y* 2 + 1 : pos.y * 2 - 1;
        InputDirection = new Vector3 (x, 0, y);
        InputDirection = (InputDirection.magnitude > 1) ? InputDirection.normalized : InputDirection;
        joyStickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (InputDirection.x * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 3)
            , InputDirection.z * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 3));
    }
}
public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped){
    OnDrag (ped);
}
public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped){
    InputDirection = Vector3.zero;
    joyStickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector3.zero;
    Debug.Log("Unpress");
}
public float Horizontal()
{
    if (InputDirection.x != 0)
        return InputDirection.x;        
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
}
public float Vertical()
{
    if (InputDirection.z != 0)
        return InputDirection.z;
    else
        return Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
}
}
```

Here is my virtual joystick controller script. Now how can I use this for control fps character controller movement both forward and side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPS uses [`CharacterController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html). You move CharacterController with [`CharacterController.Move`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html) and the Move function take `Vector3` as parameter.

All you have to do is pass in `InputDirection` from your Visual Joystick to the `Move` parameter.

```
float speed = 20;
CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
controller.Move(InputDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Or

Use the `Horizontal()` and `Vertical()` functions from your Visual Joystick.

```
public float speed = 6.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
public float gravity = 20.0F;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
void Update() {
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        moveDirection = new Vector3(Horizontal(), 0, Vertical());
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= speed;
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;

    }
    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```